# Phonegap + Facebook

Tags: javascript, android, ios, facebook, cordova

I want to integrate a Facebook "`like`" button in my hybrid app with Facebook javascript SDK plugin. The "`like`" button works perfectly on a browser, but the like button doesn't show up when I build the project with `Phonegap 3.7.0` and run it on `Android(5.0)` and `iOS(8.1.2)`

I tried this: https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin/blob/master/platforms/pg-build/README.md but still no like button...

I hope someone can help me,

Thanks in advance!

HTML:

```
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale = 1.0">

    <script src="js/cordova/cordova.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <!-- Facebook SDK plugin -->
    <div id="fb-root"></div>


    <div class="uitje_detail_bot_content">
        <div class="uitje_detail_social_media">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.mamyloe.nl/uitjes/{{uitje.id}}" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="http://www.mamyloe.nl/uitjes/{{uitje.id}}" data-text="{{uitje.title}} |" data-via="httpstwittercommamyloe" data-size="large" data-count="none">Tweet</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

Javascript:

```
function getFacebook() {
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB.init({
        appId: 'xxx',
        xfbml: true,
        version: 'v2.3'
    });
};

(function (d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {
        return;
    }
    js = d.createElement(s);
    js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/nl_NL/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));};
```

XML config:

```
<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect" version="0.9.0">
    <param name="APP_ID" value="xxx" />
    <param name="APP_NAME" value="Mamyloe app" />
</gap:plugin>

            <access origin="*" />

        <feature name="Accelerometer">
            <param name="ios-package"     value="CDVAccelerometer" />
        </feature>
        <feature name="Geolocation">
            <param name="ios-package"     value="CDVLocation" />
        </feature>
        <feature name="Geolocation">
            <param name="android-package"   value="org.apache.cordova.geolocation.GeoBroker" />
        </feature>
        <feature name="Camera">
            <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.camera.CameraLauncher" />
        </feature>
        <feature name="Camera">
            <param name="ios-package" value="CDVCamera" />
        </feature>
        <feature name="File">
            <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.FileUtils" />
        </feature>
        <feature name="FileTransfer">
            <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.FileTransfer" />
        </feature>
        <feature name="File">
            <param name="ios-package" value="CDVFile" />
        </feature>
        <feature name="FileTransfer">
            <param name="ios-package" value="CDVFileTransfer" />
        </feature>
        <feature name="org.apache.cordova.facebook.Connect">
            <param name="android-package value="org.apache.cordova.facebook.ConnectPlugin" />
        </feature>



        <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/camera" />
        <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/file" />
        <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/geolocation"/>
        <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network" />
```

Answer (score 0):

@Tim,

I do not see your CSS. There is clearly an `class="fb-like"` in your HTML. It is quite likely you need to add that URL for the image to your access class. Either that or change the CSS so you can keep the image locally.

However, I could be wrong, as I cannot see the CSS.

Jesse

Comment: Hi Jesse,

Thanks for your reply, I don't think it's a CSS problem. As I understand let the Javascript SDK show a button. But when I debug the app in a common browser and in gapdebug I got totally different element output. I think the facebook javascript SDK never executed when I run it on a mobile device.

Comment: Open up your CSS. Look for the class *fb-like* it is likely a url(). Whatever you think is apparently wrong, since you are nowhere closer to a solution.

Comment: But which URL did you mean? I dont't have the "fb- like" class in my CSS, which URL should I put in then? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have in your code:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.mamyloe.nl/uitjes/{{uitje.id}}" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div>
```

The first "class" in your `<div>` says *"fb-like"*. Somewhere in your CSS it has to have a .fb-like If you do not, this does not make sense.

On the image `url()`, see: [CSS background-image Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp)

Jesse

Comment: I tried your solution but it didn't work, what I expected. First of all the javascript code you get from the Facebook developer is responsible for showing the like button. Since the Javascript code will not run in a mobile device there is no button. So the question is why does the Javascript code runs in a common browser (Firefox for example) and not when I build my project in Phonegap and run it on a mobile device. I have added the facebook-connect-plugin which allows you to use javascript code from Facebook developer in a native way.

Comment: I'm not sure what to make of it when you say, *the (code) is responsible for showing the like button*. Something does not seem right.  However, the alternative is that Facebook used some corner case in Javascript that is not supported with the Javascript engine that Phonegap uses. NOTE:  Javascript varies widely between webbrowsers and mobile devices. It is possible you have hit a JS bug that FB did not yet hit. I'll track this StackOverflow issue and if I find something I will get back to you.

Comment: That's fine, thank you anyway for the effort to help :) I will also investigate this further.